# Reverse searching through a matrix in excel

Tags: excel

I'm working off this post: [Formula to find the header index of the first non blank cell of a range in Excel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11153987/formula-to-find-the-header-index-of-the-first-non-blank-cell-of-a-range-in-excel)

Where the formula is: `=IF(COUNTA(B2:Z2),INDEX(B$1:Z$1,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(B2:Z2<>"",0),0)),"")`

It searches the matrix row from right to left, to find the first value, and then pick the corresponding date from the column header.

How would I reverse the equation, so it searches from the left to right. Finding the last date rather than the first?

Thanks

*** edit ***

[image]

The formula is searching from left to right. For "Rob" it starts at B3 to F3, giving the answer "15-01-01" ... but the answer I want is "15-01-04" as that would search the row from right to left.

For Kyle the correct answer should be "15-01-02"

And for Adam, the correct answer should be "15-01-05"

Does that clear things up?

Comment: I'll update the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something similar to [this](https://superuser.com/questions/852928/how-to-find-address-of-last-used-cell-in-row-for-use-in-formula) might be what you are looking for. You would need to adjust the `LOOKUP` to return a result from a different array than the lookup array though, something like this:

```
=LOOKUP(9.99E+307,B3:F3,$B$2:$F$2)
```

If you put that in H3 and copy it down it should return the results you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

how about using `LARGE` (or `AGGREGATE`):

```
LARGE(IF(D1:H1<>"",1) * COLUMN(D1:H1) - COLUMN(D1) + 1,COLUMN(D1:H1) - COLUMN(D1) + 1)
```

This gives the largest column number, so you can wrap an `INDEX` around this formula to get the Dates.

(This needs to be entered with CSE)